# How to change contents of a line number in python vim module?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to create a simple vim plugin, and am encountering some problems. How do I edit the contents inside a line number? For example, in syntax plugins like ale, syntastic, neomake tc., they display the errors right next to the line number.

```
   1 | ...code
>> 2 | ...code
-- 3 | ...code
```

Is it possible to do this in the vim python module or within VimL? If so, how would one do it? I have checked the documentation [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html), but couldn't find anything related to editing the contents of the line number.
Any help is appreciated, like documentation or what commands are needed. Thanks!

Comment: There is an example at the linked docs that "*sets a line in the buffer*". Any problem with it?

Comment: @phd I'm sorry but I tried that and it is only the lines themselves, not the contents of the line numbers, for example, the left-hand side of the example I gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vim has built-in `sign`, you can define and remove signs to achieve that. Many plugins use sign too.

```
:h sign
```

Read it, and try some examples in the doc.

Comment: Yes, this is it!! I can use the vim.command method to define the signs. Thank you so much!!